# debug tools for kivy/python app in android

Tags: python, android, debugging, kivy

I wrote a simple code in kivy/python. In fact, it is just a hello world example! The app works fine on Windows but crashes on the mobile device. I don't know how to debug the kivy app!

In fact, I need to debug my app by displaying logs from the mobile device in real time.

could anyone suggest a program that can help me? Is Android Studio the only choice?

any help is appreciated. thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.